# php- How to foreach mysqli_fetch_rows result in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I want to fetch rows in my mysql DB and show them using html. I am currently using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
$records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   foreach ( $row as $field => $v) {
        echo "$field -> $v <br> ";
       }
}
```

It produces the output as:

```
0 -> 38
1 -> Ashish
2 -> Description yet to put
3 -> http://google.com
4 -> 5
0 -> 12
1 -> David
2 -> Long description goes here...
3 -> http://facebook.com
4 -> 9
```

I want it to put all the data into as html (with loop) as:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
<h3>HERE I WANT TO PUT VALUE OF FIELD 1</h3>
<p>HERE I WANT TO PUT VALUE OF FIELD 2</p>
<p>HERE I WANT TO PUT VALUE OF FIELD 3</p>
<p>HERE I WANT TO PUT VALUE OF FIELD 4</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: that is just echoing an html markup with some values, just try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may look this:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
    $records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       ?>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
    <h3><? echo $row['field-1'] ?></h3>
    <p><? echo $row['field-2'] ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row['field-3'] ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row['field-4'] ?></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
       <?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
    $records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {?>

           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
                <h3><?php echo $row[1]; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $row[2]; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $row[3]; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $row[4]; ?></p> 
             </div>
          </div>
    <?php    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
$records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo '<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">'; 
$bool = true;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   foreach ( $row as $field => $v) {
        if($bool) echo '<h3>$field -> $v</h3>';
        $bool = false;
        else echo "<p>$field -> $v </p> ";
   }
}
```